# Updating to old Mercurial revisions with subrepos that have moved

Tags: mercurial, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

Our project has a couple of remote subrepos in it, and their addresses have recently moved from `http://host/path` to `http://other_host/path`. How can one go back to a revision from, say, last month, where Mercurial thinks the subrepo can be found at `http://host/path`?

```
$ hg -v up -d 1/20/2012
Found revision 1091 from Fri Jan 20 10:22:29 2012 -0600
resolving manifests
abort: error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it


$ hg --debug up -d 1/20/2012
Found revision 1091 from Fri Jan 20 10:22:29 2012 -0600
resolving manifests

<snip...>

subrepo merge 0f0f2b807811+ 0908d5249a6f 0f0f2b807811
  subrepo external/our_remote_repo: both sides changed, merge with https://old_host/external/our_remote_repo:c66cf52ce1f240193190cec392d889618c09f22b:hg
using https://old_host/external/our_remote_repo
sending capabilities command
using auth.old_host.* for authentication
abort: error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/subrepos) you can use [subpaths] in hgrc to [remap such urls](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#subpaths).

This boils down to defining subrepositories source locations rewriting rules in the form of

```
<pattern> = <replacement>
```

where pattern is a regular expression matching the source and replacement is the replacement string used to rewrite it. Groups can be matched in pattern and referenced in replacements. For instance:

```
http://server/(.*)-hg/ = http://hg.server/\1/
```

rewrites

```
http://server/foo-hg/ into http://hg.server/foo/.
```

Answer (score -5):

You can't do it. Mercurial returns in the state, which it had exactly at this revision (URL of subrepo, revision in subrepo)